# ErrorBars with BarChart, ChartLabels are not working?

Tags: graphics, plotting

In the [Add Error Bars to Charts and Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html) How To in the Mathematica documentation a function `ErrorBar` is given:

```
errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, meta_] := 
   Block[{error}, 
      error = Flatten[meta];
      error = If[error === {}, 0, Last[error]]; 
      {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value, meta], 
         {Black, Line[{
             {{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, y1 + error}}, 
             {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 + error}}, 
             {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 - error}}
            }]
       }}
      ]
```

that adds error bars to `BarChart`. Here is an example using some random data with random errors:

```
chartData = MapThread[{#1 -> #2} &, {RandomReal[1, 10], RandomReal[0.1, 10]}]
```

and some random labels:

```
labels = ToString /@ RandomReal[100000, 10]
```

Now plotting it, as per the tutorial:

```
BarChart[chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"], 
ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]]
```

The labels are:

```
{"99539.6", "17862.9", "14683.4", "32667.2", "42690.", 
 "70230.8", "59050.4", "59204.7", "9138.2", "19080.3"}
```

However, in the plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first label is repeated incorrectly for all the bars, what's going on here? Without error bars the labels on the plot are correct:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the original code, `chartData` is of the form `{{value1 -> error1}, {value2 -> error2}, ... }`, but it should be of the form `{value1 -> error1, value2 -> error2, ... }`. To get the right labels you could do something like (note the missing brackets in `chartData`)

```
chartData = 
 MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {RandomReal[1, 10], RandomReal[0.1, 10]}];

BarChart[chartData, 
 ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why use `#1 -> #2 &` and not simply `Rule`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would suspect `#1 -> #2&` is less opaque than `Rule` as I don't know how many users know that they're equivalent.